# How to adjust slideshow and enable people to click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really bad with Javascript and is still learning. Recently, I have the idea of using an image slider for the website I am designing and I tried the Image Slider code from W3school. I tested the code, and tried the demo on the website.

In the website, I was able to click on the grey dots to move between pictures, however, when I pasted the code on my page, I was unable to move the images through clicking(the grey button cannot be clicked), and the only way the image is able to change is through its own animation time. I do not know what is wrong with it and I hope someone will be able to help me and tell me what's wrong.

Below is my Javascript code:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

My HTML Slider code:

```
 <div class="jumbotron" style="background:transparent !important;">
    <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <img src="Images/Bulldog.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 300px">
            <div class="text"><h2>Bulldog</h2></div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="Images/Corgeek.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 300px">
            <div class="text"><h2>Corgi</h2></div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img src="Images/HairyDog.jpg" style="width:100%;height: 300px;">
            <div class="text"><h2>Furry Dog</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, is there any better way to create a slideshow? If there is, it would be appreciated if there are links or solutions for me to see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but you are using a `jumbotron` class, which indicates you are already loading Bootstrap.  If this is the case, you already have a slideshow available to you.

You can read about the slideshow(carousel) here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

It will likely be easier to use, and less error prone than what you are currently working with.

Comment: Yes I am using Bootstrap. Thank you for the link, sir. If I may ask, is there one where the carousel gets automated? I want it to be like a slideshow and users can also click between the different images to check on the content.

Comment: Yes, in the documentation there is a way to fully automate it, or to click between images.

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try it.